# Write word count frequency from python list into a csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a list as below (test_list)
I am trying to do word count frequency, sort by counts and want to write as a csv along with header.
I have tried as below.

```
test_list = ['ball', 'cat', 'mat', 'ball', 'cat', 'ball', 'ball', 'ink']
items = pd.Series(test_list).value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False)
items.columns = ['items', '#counts']
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\word_count.csv',header=True)
```

But my output csv is without header and there is 0 on top as below

[image]

Expected output as below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just chain [`reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) method in your current code:

```
items = pd.Series(test_list).value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False).reset_index()
```

Now Finally:

```
items.columns = ['items', '#counts']
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\word_count.csv',header=True,index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

convert series to dataframe and then rename the columns.
Finally, save the df.

```
df = items.to_frame(name = 'count')
df.index.name = 'item'
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: or `items.reset_index(name='#counts')`